# Edad con fecha de nacimiento

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un vector de caracteres con fechas de nacimiento (en R) tipo "mes/día/año" , el vector consta de 161 fechas. Necesito obtener un vector numérico con las edades. ¿Hay forma de hacerlo de manera "rapida" sin tener que hacer todas las diferencias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No encontré una función que haga exactamente eso, pero usando la librería `lubridate` es bastante fácil y resuelve automáticamente problemas del manejo de fechas como los bisiestos y cosas por el estilo.

Simulo unos datos:

```
library(lubridate)
fechas <- c("01/01/1900", "25/03/2019", "25/03/2021")
```

Con esta línea se resuelve el problema:

```
floor(time_length(ymd(Sys.Date()) - dmy(fechas), unit = "year"))

[1] 121   2   0
```

Si quieres tomar una referencia diferente al día de la fecha (hoy) para hacer el cálculo puedes reemplazar `Sys.Date()` con cualquier fecha arbitraria.

Uso las funciones `ymd` (Año/Mes/Día) y `dmy` (Día/Mes/Año) para convertir cadenas de caracteres a objetos de la clase fecha. Si tus fechas están en otros formatos tendrías que usar la función apropiada.

Va el mismo código, pero extendido y con comentarios.

```
floor(           #Para que redonde los años hacia abajo porque son años cumplidos, time_length regresa un double
  time_length(   #Regresa el período de tiempo y se pueden pasar un argumento para que sea en años
    ymd(Sys.Date()) - dmy(fechas), #El signo - funciona como difftime, regresa la diferencia en días. Sys.date() regresa el día de hoy
  unit = "year"))   #Acá está la unidad de tiempo para time_length
```